# Are there any GUI SVN file management software for Windows?

Tags: windows, software-rec, svn, gui

Excluding TortoiseSVN, I was looking for software with a similar interface to [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/), for OSX.

The only requirement is that the SVN software runs independently of Windows Explorer, preferably with its own window (ala Versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RapidSVN](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/) is an alternative, but TourtiseSVN is really your best option. RapidSVN is portable however, and runs in its own GUI.

Comment: The last time I used RapidSVN, repositories checked out with TortoiseSVN in Windows are incompatible, and therefore unable to be checked out with RapidSVN in Linux (some SVN version mismatch). So if you intend to use RapidSVN and TortoiseSVN both, test if they are indeed compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [SmartSVN](http://www.syntevo.com/smartsvn/index.html) for many years and find it very good.